# What does get() makes difference in SharedFlow if I use in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any difference between this two?

```
private val _userReviewData = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>()    
val userReviewData get() = _userReviewData.asSharedFlow()
```

OR

```
private val _userReviewData = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>()
    val userReviewData = _userReviewData.asSharedFlow()
```

I don't understand any diff yet!

Also `.asSharedFlow()` should I defined explicitly or not?

Comment: The whole point of this construct is so you don't expose a `MutableSharedFlow` so `.asSharedFlow()` is required. Converting `MutableSharedFlow` to just `SharedFlow` so its read only for callers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `get()` i.e. provide a custom getter, then every time you access `userReviewData`, it will call `_userReviewData.asSharedFlow()` which is unnecessary. It's better to create a `SharedFlow` instance once and use it instead of creating multiple such instances.